Contact Form 7 not exibiting field
I completed contact form 7 using the code below, but when I display it in the field that should show WhatsApp, the code is printed, not the form, as shown in the print annexe. Can you help me solve the question? Thanks so much in advance

 Nome
[text* your-name autocomplete:name placeholder "Como lhe devemos chamar?"] 
 Email
[email* your-email autocomplete:email placeholder "seu melhor email para contato?"] 
 WhatsApp
[tel* your-whatsapp autocomplete:tel placeholder "Seu número de WhatsApp com DDD" pattern:'(?:+55\s?)?(?:([1-9]{2})\s?)?[9][1-9]\d{3}-?\d{4}'] 
[acceptance acceptance-750] Declaro aceitar compartilhar meus dados com o mkt da AD Boutique, e que a qualquer momento puderei descadastrar-me [/acceptance]
[submit "Iniciar"]
exhibition of form in screen
To exhibit a form, but I got the code
The pattern showed shluld force a format of WhatsApp like +55.11.91300-3948
